# How to disable trackball rotate event and call the custom rotate event and set rotate speed in custom event

Tags: javascript, three.js

Here I'm trying to disable the trackball control rotate event and to call my custom rotate event. When it is tried in OrbitControl (controls.enableRotate = false;) is doing the job but when comes to trackball control it executes both the trackball control and custom event rotate functionalities. Here's the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/azso936f/1/
In the fiddle the rotate operation works on mousemove and when we mousedown the rotate functionality of trackballcontrol works too

```
var scene, renderer, camera;
    var cube;
    var controls;
    var containerWidth = window.innerWidth,
        containerHeight = window.innerHeight;
    var isDragging = false;
    var previousMousePosition = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
    init();

    animate();

    function init() {
        configureRenderer();

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        configureCube();
        configureCamera();
        configureLight();
        configureControls();
    }

    function configureRenderer() {
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true,
            alpha: true
        });
        renderer.setSize(containerWidth, containerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        window.onresize = function () {
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            if (controls)
                controls.handleResize();
        }

        renderer.domElement.addEventListener("wheel", function (e) {
            const delta = event.deltaY;

            let x = 2 * event.clientX / window.innerWidth - 1;
            let y = 1 - 2 * event.clientY / window.innerHeight;
            let cursorpos = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, 1);

            cursorpos.unproject(camera);

            let dir = new THREE.Vector3().copy(cursorpos).sub(camera.position).normalize();
            let shift = new THREE.Vector3().copy(dir).multiplyScalar(delta * 0.1);

            camera.position.add(shift);
            controls.position0.add(shift);
            controls.target.add(shift);
        });

        renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {

            isDragging = true;
        });

        renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
            isDragging = true;
            //console.log(e);
            var deltaMove = {
                x: e.offsetX - previousMousePosition.x,
                y: e.offsetY - previousMousePosition.y
            };

            if (isDragging) {

                var deltaRotationQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion()
                    .setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(
                        toRadians(deltaMove.y * 1),
                        toRadians(deltaMove.x * 1),
                        0,
                        'XYZ'
                    ));

                cube.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(deltaRotationQuaternion, cube.quaternion);
            }

            previousMousePosition = {
                x: e.offsetX,
                y: e.offsetY
            };
        });

        function toRadians(angle) {
            return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
        }
        renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {
            isDragging = false;
        })
    }


    function configureCube() {
        var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20);
        var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: 0xff0000
        });
        cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
        cube.position.set(50, 0, 0);

        scene.add(cube);
    }

    function configureCamera() {
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, containerWidth / containerHeight, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.set(0, 160, 400);
        camera.lookAt(scene);
    }

    function configureLight() {
        pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.0, 100000);
        pointLight.position.set(0, 300, 200);
        scene.add(pointLight);
    }

    function configureControls() {
        controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        // configuration of controls
        controls.rotateSpeed = 5.0;
        controls.zoomSpeed = 0.0;
        controls.panSpeed = 2.0;
        controls.staticMoving = true;
        controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0;

    }

    function animate() {
        controls.update();
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the fiddle the rotate operation works on mousemove and when we mousedown the rotate functionality of trackballcontrol works too

It is sufficient to set the rotation speed (`.rotateSpeed`) of `THREE.TrackballControls` to 0:

```js
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

controls.rotateSpeed = 0.0;
```

---

The rotation speed can be changed by scaling the `THREE.Euler` angles:

```js
renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    const that = this;
    var rotateSpeed = 0.1;
    var deltaMove = {
        x: e.offsetX - previousMousePosition.x,
        y: e.offsetY - previousMousePosition.y
    };

    if (isDragging) {
        var deltaRotationQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion()
            .setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(
                toRadians(deltaMove.y * rotateSpeed),
                toRadians(deltaMove.x * rotateSpeed),
                0,
                'XYZ'
            ));
        cube.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(deltaRotationQuaternion, cube.quaternion);
    }

    previousMousePosition = {
        x: e.offsetX,
        y: e.offsetY
    };
});
```

Comment: But I have disabled the controls of trackball (controls.enabled = false) and trying to handle the speed of rotate in mousemove event

Comment: @AjayVenkatesh I can't find "`controls.enabled`" in your code. What do you mean by *" trying to handle the speed of rotate in mousemove event"*?

Comment: @AjayVenkatesh Now I am completely confused. Finally what is the question? Your code works fine.

Comment: yes @Rabbid76. I want to decrease the rotation speed of the cube

Comment: @AjayVenkatesh You've to scale the euler angles.

Comment: Can you suggest me some examples @Rabbid76

Comment: So found the solution @Rabbid76
Where I created a new variable for zoomSpeed with less than default value and multiplied the with the Radiant